# How to solve Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten

Tags: vue.js

I have seen many questions and answer but they don't solve my problem, I'm just trying to show/hide when I click in the parent components menu button the drawer should open, after the first-time load it works fine but when I close this it shows me this error. I just want to pass true or false in the props

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "drawer"
```

This what I'm trying to do.

#### In the parent

```
<template>
    <div @click="drawer = true" class="hamburger">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div>

   <mobile-drawer-menu :drawer="drawer"/>
</template>

<script>
   import MobileDrawerMenu from "./MobileDrawerMenu";

   export default {
     components : {
        MobileDrawerMenu
    },

     data() {
        return {
            drawer : false,
        }
     },

   }
</script>
```

#### In child

```
<template>
    <div v-if="drawer" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-200">
        <div @click="drawer = false" class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="drawer-wrapper">
            <div class="drawer-close">
               <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                  <svg @click="drawer = false"></svg>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                     
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: "MobileDrawerMenu",
      props : {
        drawer : {
            type : Boolean,
            required : true
        }
     },
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.sync` [modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier), and update the prop with `$emit` :

```
<template>
    <div @click="drawer = true" class="hamburger">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div>

   <mobile-drawer-menu :drawer.sync="drawer"/>
</template>

<script>
   import MobileDrawerMenu from "./MobileDrawerMenu";

   export default {
     components : {
        MobileDrawerMenu
    },

     data() {
        return {
            drawer : false,
        }
     },

   }
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="drawer" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-200">
        <div @click="$emit('update:drawer', false)" class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="drawer-wrapper">
            <div class="drawer-close">
               <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                  <svg @click="$emit('update:drawer', false)"></svg>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                     
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: "MobileDrawerMenu",
      props : {
        drawer : {
            type : Boolean,
            required : true
        }
     },
   }
</script>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/176oba9n/

Comment: no, `.sync` is a shorthand wich create an @update internaly and update the prop on parent

Comment: Yeah, but the situation, when child depends on parent component is left. I think ref is better. But this solution is good too.

Comment: It shows me this error now `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"` @Hans

Comment: Yes this working :), thanks both of you guys, you guys are really awesome

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate your prop in the child component. You can emit event and close in parent controller or just let `drawer` be only in child component and toggle open via function, using ref:

Parent:

```js
<template>
    <div @click="open" class="hamburger">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div>

   <mobile-drawer-menu ref="modal"/>
</template>

<script>
    import MobileDrawerMenu from "./MobileDrawerMenu";

    export default {
        components : {
            MobileDrawerMenu
        },
        methods: {
            open() {
                this.$refs.modal.open();
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Child:

```js
<template>
    <div v-if="drawer" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-200">
        <div @click="close" class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="drawer-wrapper">
            <div class="drawer-close">
               <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                  <svg @click="close"></svg>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                     
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "MobileDrawerMenu",
        data: () => ({
            drawer: false
        }),
        methods: {
            open() {
                this.drawer = true;
            },
            close() {
                this.drawer = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you see, you can access child methods(and state values) using ref.
More about ref [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).
Also you can do this using emit, if you need to keep `drawer` property in parent component, you can read about it [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: This is nicely working :), Thank you Brother @Asi Ple